# Find the permutation of numpy array to align it with another array?

Tags: python, numpy, permutation

I have two numpy arrays such as

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.array([3, 1, 4])
y = np.array([4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
```

each containing unique values. The values in `x` are guaranteed to be a subset of those in `y`.

**I would like to find the index of each element of `x` in the array `y`**.

In the array above, this would be

```py
[1, 3, 0]
```

So far I have been finding the indices one at a time in a loop:

```py
idxs = []
for val in x:
     idxs.append(np.argwhere(y == val)[0,0])
```

But this is slow when my arrays are large.

**Is there a more efficient way to do this?**

Answer (score 4):

Using list.index() method improves the time significantly

```
y = y.tolist()
indexes = [y.index(i) for i in x]
```

Here is a quick timing results

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

x = np.array([3, 1, 4])
y = np.array([4, 3, 2, 1])

total_time = timeit.timeit('[np.argwhere(y == i)[0, 0] for i in x]',
                           'from __main__ import ' + ', '.join(globals()), number=10000)
print("using argwhere = ", total_time)

total_time = timeit.timeit('[y.tolist().index(i) for i in x]',
                           'from __main__ import ' + ', '.join(globals()), number=10000)
print("using list index = ", total_time)
```

using argwhere =  0.2716948229999616

using list index =  0.05231958099966505

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.isin` in combination with `np.argwhere`

```
[np.argwhere(el==y)[0,0] for el in x]
```

Comment: I am hoping to preserve the order of the indices so that `all(y[idxs] == x)` should be `True`. Is there any way to modify your solution to achieve this?

Comment: This might be a bit slower since we are using a loop but its working and might be faster tha your first try

Comment: Some quick timing experiments suggest it is about the same speed